# Every time I run a meteor command, I get an error

Tags: windows, meteor, command-prompt

Every time I run a meteor command, I get the error:

```
C:\Users\brand\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\isobuild\meteor-npm.js:265
  versions: _extends({}, process.versions)
```

I think it has something to do with the new meteor update, but I am not sure. I am running windows 10. If anyone has any suggestions, that would be great.

Comment: More info [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9278)

Comment: and [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/upgrade-to-1-6-failing/40184). Some folks have had luck by nuking their node_modules with a fresh `meteor npm install` and a `meteor reset`

Comment: I did this, but I am getting same error